# TestNG - can't get input from console

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to notify the tester of a problem at @BeforeSuite.
My code prints information to the console and waits for Enter or any key.
For some reason my code is getting stuck and I don't see any error or exception.
I type enter a few times but nothing happens.
Please help.

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "suite-param" })
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext testContext, @Optional String suiteFile) throws Exception {

//some condition in here
    if (true ) {
        ConsoleLogger.info("You are running COMPARE Mode");
        ConsoleLogger.info("createBaseLine=false on your testProps");
        System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
        try {
        System.in.read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is the preferred way to get input from the user via the keyboard in a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try int i=System.in.read(); System.out.println(I); then on entering any charcter its ascii value  will be returned in response .